# copy range selected from sheet in a combobox to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

in my userform i have a combobox that allow me to select from all the sheets that exist in my workbook, what i want to is that when i select the sheet, all the ranges should be copied into another sheet if it is possible can help me please here is the code i am using for the combobox

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Const ColItems  As Long = 20
Const LetterWidth As Long = 20
Const HeightRowz As Long = 18
Const SheetID As String = "__SheetSelection"

Dim i%, TopPos%, iSet%, optCols%, intLetters%, optMaxChars%, optLeft%
Dim wsDlg As DialogSheet, objOpt As OptionButton, optCaption$, objSheet As Object
optCaption = "": i = 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.DialogSheets(SheetID).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Err.Clear

Set wsDlg = ActiveWorkbook.DialogSheets.Add
With wsDlg
.Name = SheetID
.Visible = xlSheetHidden
iSet = 0: optCols = 0: optMaxChars = 0: optLeft = 78: TopPos = 40

For Each objSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
If objSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
i = i + 1

If i Mod ColItems = 1 Then
optCols = optCols + 1
TopPos = 40
optLeft = optLeft + (optMaxChars * LetterWidth)
optMaxChars = 0
End If

intLetters = Len(objSheet.Name)
If intLetters > optMaxChars Then optMaxChars = intLetters
iSet = iSet + 1
.OptionButtons.Add optLeft, TopPos, intLetters * LetterWidth, 16.5
.OptionButtons(iSet).Text = objSheet.Name
TopPos = TopPos + 13

End If
Next objSheet

If i > 0 Then

.Buttons.Left = optLeft + (optMaxChars * LetterWidth) + 24

With .DialogFrame
.Height = Application.Max(68, WorksheetFunction.Min(iSet, ColItems) * HeightRowz + 10)
.Width = optLeft + (optMaxChars * LetterWidth) + 24
.Caption = "Select sheet to go to"
End With

.Buttons("Button 2").BringToFront
.Buttons("Button 3").BringToFront
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

If .Show = True Then
For Each objOpt In wsDlg.OptionButtons
If objOpt.Value = xlOn Then
optCaption = objOpt.Caption
Exit For
End If
Next objOpt
End If

If optCaption = "" Then
MsgBox "You did not select a worksheet.", 48, "Cannot continue"
Exit Sub
Else

MsgBox "You selected the sheet named ''" & optCaption & "''." & vbCrLf & "Click OK to go there.", 64, "FYI:"
Sheets(optCaption).Activate

End If

End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: what _"all the ranges"_ are? How is _another sheet_ supposed to be chosen/identified?

Comment: ranges reefers to column i have 5 column from A to F , and to choose from all existing sheets in combobox i just click on the combobox and then i have an other msgbox that allow me to select from the existing sheets i will download the excel file for you to see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well after searching, the solution was so simple i needed just to change this line `Sheets(optCaption).Activate` 
to

```
Sheets(optCaption).Range("A1:F10000").copy Destination:=Sheets("operations").Range("A1:F10000")
```

for those who are interested